# Yii2 Get current action in controller

Tags: yii2

How can I get current action?

This code:

```
if (!Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'lang') {
    Url::remember();
}
```

returns an error:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Getting action id is correct. Where you are calling this? Seems like `application` is not initialized at that moment. Also the check should be `if (Yii::$app->controller->action->id != 'lang')`.

Comment: from controller, from init() function. I must do this check on each page

Comment: Please add the full code where you call it to the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use [beforeAction()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#beforeAction%28%29-detail) event instead of `init()`.

Also you can simply use `$this` because it contains current controller.

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
        if ($this->action->id == 'lang') {
            Url::remember();
        }

        return true; // or false if needed
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `$this->action->id` ?

Answer (score 14):

if use Yii2 in view - try this: 
`$this->context->action->id;`

Answer (score 5):

You can get current action name by:

```
Yii::$app->controller->action->id
```

And get the controller name with this one:

```
 Yii::$app->controller->id;
```

**Note:** Remember that these will only work after the application has been initialized. Possible use: `inside a controller action`/ `inside a model` or `inside a view`

*Reference: [Class yii\web\Controller](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-controller)*

Answer (score 3):

You can get current action id by :)

```
 Yii::$app->controller->id;
```

Comment: That is how you get the controller id, not the action id.

Comment: you can get by using simpy  Yii::$app->controller->action->id;